# how to run mysql v5.5 on redhat linux

Tags: linux, mysql, redhat, path

I am new to both linux and also mysql but somehow by obtaining help from net I have installed mysql v5.5 on redhat. It starts fine, I have confirmed this by running command: "/etc/init.d/mysqld status"

I have installed required packages as well: mysql-client, -server, -test, -devel, -shared, -embedded

But I am not able to change password using command: mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password' It gives error : bash: mysqladmin: command not found. I tried searching mysqladmin by using command "find / -name mysqladmin" but it returned no result

All I can search on net is adding to path '/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin' but directory structure after installation mysql v5.5 has changed. There is no such directory like /usr/bin/local/mysql now.

please help me with how to run mysql after changing root's password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `yum whatprovides` to help find the package that contains a particular file e.g.

```
yum whatprovides /use/bin/mysqladmin
mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.x86_64 : MySQL client programs and shared libraries
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/mysqladmin
```

If you don't know where the file you are looking fore resides then you can use something like

```
yum whatprovides "*/mysqladmin"
```

Which may find other occurrences of a file called mysqladmin so it would be up to you to decide which package to install. In this particular case `/usr/bin/mysqladmin` is provided by package `mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.x86_64` and

```
yum install mysql
```

should install it for you.

Answer (score 1):

On a RHEL6.1 box mysqladmin is provided by

`mysql-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64`

You haven't specified what version of CentOS you're running but perhaps a `yum install mysql` will provide it for you. Alternatively run:

`yum whatprovides /usr/bin/mysqladmin`

and install that package.

Answer (score 0):

You can install through yum

yum install mysql-server mysql

or download from the mysql site and install using rpm command

dev.mysql.com/downloads/